# some data did not consumed by kafka-engine

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse

We are using the kafka-engine to connect kafka topic, and then MATERIALIZED VIEW to store the data.

But from time to time, some data did not consumed by kafka-engine( due to we also apply flume to put the data into hdfs file, and these missing data can be found in hdfs file).

Is there any other method to find related log to located problem except upgrade the clcikhouse server version(we are on the way to upgrade clickhouse server )

Comment: it looks like the same consumer group is shared between Kafka-engine and 'flume'.

Comment: but we are using different consume group name

Answer (score 0):

You can enable rdkafka logs by adding `<kafka><debug>all</debug></kafka>` fragment to clickhouse config.xml file

Logs will be written to /var/log/clickhouse-server/stderr file (in docker - to docker logs).

Comment: Hi, which subsection should I put inside the xml? thanks